# CFString to string?

Tags: c#, string

I have follow code to make a String to a CFString:

```
 internal static byte[] StringToCFString(string value)
    {
        byte[] b;

        b = new byte[value.Length + 10];
        b[4] = 0x8c;
        b[5] = 07;
        b[6] = 01;
        b[8] = (byte)value.Length;
        Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value, 0, value.Length, b, 9);
        return b;
    }

    public static byte[] StringToCString(string value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[value.Length + 1];
        Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value, 0, value.Length, bytes, 0);
        return bytes;
    }
```

How I can get a CFString to String back?
(C#.Net 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this...

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(value, 9, value.Length - 9);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private String CFString2String(IntPtr intPtr)
{
    byte size = Marshal.ReadByte(intPtr, 8);
    byte[] b = new byte[size];
    Marshal.Copy(IntPtr.Add(intPtr, 9), b, 0, size);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is error 
when the parameter "value" is utf8 string
such as Chinese.

if you need CFString to String back

please use the CoreFoundation.CFString with constructor CFString(IntPtr ptr)

the parameter "ptr" is a pointer to a CFString.

CoreFoundation.CFString -> https://github.com/isnowrain/CoreFoundation