# How to cast string to cfstring in C#

Tags: c#, string, cfstring

I have the following code to convert a String to a CFString and backwarts:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\ayi\Desktop\Failed\AngryBirds.ipa";

IntPtr p_path = __CFStringMakeConstantString(path);

CoreFoundation.CFString cfstring = new CoreFoundation.CFString(p_path);

string result = cfstring.ToString();
```

The problem is `path != result` where the `path` contain some Chinese characters like  `@"C:\Users\ayi\Desktop\中文\AngryBirds.ipa";`

How can I cast string that contain Chinese to cfstring in C#?

Comment: See similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249503/cfstring-to-string

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a c-like string to CFString with the `CFStringCreateWithCString` function:

```
CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, myCString, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Then you need to figure-out how to convert C# String to c-like string. I am unfortunately not a C# developer, so here is a link which seems ok:

[C++ .NET convert System::String to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300718/c-net-convert-systemstring-to-stdstring)

Note: use `std::string::c_str()` to convert C++ string to c-like string `myCppString.c_str()`. This operation is mostly accessing inner memory, so very fast.